# Считывание байтов c Arduino

Tags: java, arduino, port, byte

с Arduino модет прийти любое число, состоящее из 1-3 цифр. Использую вот этот код для считывания:

```
 StringFP = new String(serialPortARD.readBytes(1), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

Где вместо 1 может быть любое число байтов от 1 до 3.
Вопрос. Как правильно считывать?

Comment: Почему-бы не передавать по три байта каждый раз?

Comment: лучше способ вывода на ардуино поменять, чем пытаться таймауты ловить. Добивать строку до фиксированного размера, или завершать каждую порцию данных переводом строки, например.

Comment: @Ocenic, потому что это данные с датчика.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить в скетч что-то вроде этого:

```
if (number < 10)
   Serial.print("00");
else if (number < 100)
   Serial.print('0');
Serial.println(number, DEC);
```

Comment: Уже сделал. Слегка иначе, но все работает.